# Change value of an object in JSON based on another key value - shell

Tags: shell, jq

in shell I have the following object

```
[
{
  "ParameterKey":"a",
  "ParameterValue":"1"
},
{
  "ParameterKey":"b",
  "ParameterValue":"2"
},
{
  "ParameterKey":"c",
  "ParameterValue":"3"
},
{
  "ParameterKey":"d",
  "ParameterValue":"4"
}
]
```

I need to find out how to access the ParameterKeys 'b' and 'd' in an optimal way (WITHOUT using array indexes) using e.g. jq so that the resulting array would be:

```
[
{
  "ParameterKey":"a",
  "ParameterValue":"1"
},
{
  "ParameterKey":"b",
  "ParameterValue":"5"
},
{
  "ParameterKey":"c",
  "ParameterValue":"3"
},
{
  "ParameterKey":"d",
  "ParameterValue":"6"
}
]
```

Comment: thx for the -1, care to explain?

Comment: I did not give you the -1 but probably it's because you haven't shown what you have tried.  Also, where do the pairs ["b", 5] and ["d", 6] come from? See [mcve] for guidance.

Comment: I cannot help but think this is very much nitpicking, since it is obviously clear what the question is and how to answer it (demonstrated by the accepted answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will change a single ParameterValue for a ParameterName

```
jq '[.[] | select(.ParameterKey == "b") .ParameterValue |= "5"]'

[
  {
    "ParameterKey": "a",
    "ParameterValue": "1"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "b",
    "ParameterValue": "5"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "c",
    "ParameterValue": "3"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "d",
    "ParameterValue": "4"
  }
]
```

[Try it online!](https://jqplay.org/s/YJTfEaVMbd)

If you do not want to hardcode the key and value, you can use `--arg`

```
jq --arg key "b" --arg value "5" '[.[] | select(.ParameterKey == $key) .ParameterValue |= $value]' </tmp/data.json

[
  {
    "ParameterKey": "a",
    "ParameterValue": "1"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "b",
    "ParameterValue": "5"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "c",
    "ParameterValue": "3"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "d",
    "ParameterValue": "4"
  }
]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you're asking but the following jq filter solves one interpretation of the question:

```
map(if .ParameterKey == "b" then .ParameterValue = "5"
    elif .ParameterKey == "d" then .ParameterValue = "6"
    else . end)
```

Here's an alternative approach using a single JSON object to define the key/value pairs defining the update:

```
map( {(.ParameterKey): .ParameterValue} )
| add + {b:"5", d:"6"}
| to_entries
| map( {ParameterKey: .key, ParameterValue: .value} )
```